# Google Analytics Marketplace

Tags: 7, google-analytics

I'm running Drupal 7 along with the Google Analytics module. I have an eCommerce Marketplace setup with store fronts and unique products per store. I'd like to have analytics per store so that each store owner can see the traffic coming to their page/products.

I'm using Organic Groups to setup the stores with Group Type: Store and Group Content: Products. I have custom variables setup relating to the Group Reference.

My question is:

How can I filter page requests in Google Analytics to specifically those relating to a certain group/store so that when a store owner views their analytics they are only seeing the requests for their "pages"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option may be to simply bring the Google Analytics data into your website, where you can then leverage the power of views to display the view statistics for the exact pages you want.

If you use the [Google Analytics Statistics](https://drupal.org/project/ga_stats) module, you should be able to set it up to download view stats either for the past 24 hours, 48 hours, week, month, etc and it'll do that as you run cron.  The config page is at /admin/config/system/ga_stats.  After connecting it to your Google Account by typing in your Google Login, the module setup looks something like this:

[image]

Then - you can view your Google Analytics statistics on your site (rather than through the Google Analytics interface) and can create any number of views for your different page groups as you want.  The module integrates with views...

Let us know if that works for you.

I've only recently found out about this module and started using it, so I'd be interested in any others chiming in here...